# C guessing game between two players with visual output

Tags: c

I have been given the assignment to create a quite complicated to me, but simple to some C game.  The program will run and generate 25 random numbers between 1 to 100 (no repeats). The game is between two users.

Both the players will get two guesses each time. Every correct guess will be counted as 1 correct answer and will be displayed on the screen in the board.
The player having more number of correct guesses will be a winner.
The game will continue until the board is completely revealed.

1. The first screen should ask the user for his name, print a welcome message, and displays an empty 5x5 board.  But this 5x5 board has the values in it internally
2. Now the program should ask the number of players (1 or 2)
3. If one, ask one name and second is computer and if 2 ask two names
4. For playing against computer, you are asked for two guesses and every correct guess is shown on the board.
5. Now 2 guesses for computer would be taken and shown on the screen.

I have tried everything to my knowledge to complete this but I lack a full understanding of C. Any help would be appreciated. I did not include my code because, honestly its just a mess and does not even run.

[image]

I would like to see someone be able to make such a game, so that I can study the logic. NOT COPY THE WORK

Comment: What kind of help do you expect from us. Please ask a specific question.

Comment: Split up your complicated assignment, into steps you can handle. If necessary go back to a hello world. See this very helpful article. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/

Comment: I would like to see someone be able to make such a game, so that I can study the logic. @machine_1

Comment: Would you like help according to the compromise described here?  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: sounds like you are in a C course. So go ask your TA / teacher / tutor for help

Comment: Having somebody here make such a game and giving it to you is not how things work here. While you do not actually want somebody to do your homework for you, it is still the same from point of view of somebody doing it for you.

Comment: This assignment is large enough in scope that you have had how long to study it and do work with it?

Comment: There are some questions with upvoted answers on StackOverflow where an asker and a patient answerer cooperated according to the compromise and ended with a very accepted answer (judged by several upvotes). So please consider the offer.

Comment: This question, as most which give the strong impression of being a blind homework dump (in spite of serious attempts to trigger anything to the contrary...), is too broad to be answered. (Sorry @pm100, I trust you will not begrudge me the 30 upvote points if we manage to actually close this.)

Comment: @Yunnosch I dont mind. I hope my answer helps OP a bit. However I do think it is reasonable for a question thats says 'i really dont know where to start, please give me a few pointers'. Really that is the schools job - but maybe its not possible in this case.

Comment: There are some great and upvoted hint-by-hint answers and yours could have become one with OP accepting your very generous offer. @pm100 Alas, it was not to be.

Answer (score 3):

Simple steps. Start small and grow.

Easy one is to remove all questions to the user(s). Hard code the answers in the program. You can retrofit the IO later.

Start with a way ot generating 25 random numbers and load them into an array. Place the array in a global variable. You need a another array to show when a number is sucessfully guessed.

Now write a function to display that guessed array as 5X5.

Gradually build the program up

*Always* make functions

- generate_array
- show_guessed
- ....

If get stuck on specific things then post a new question.

Comment: I assume you started to do the hint-by-hint kind of homework answer. My respect for that. Would you like to indicate that you will reward visible effort by OP with more hints? Sorry if I read too much into this, not intending to put pressure on you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but a very long comment with some requests for more information and effort.

The problem I have with your request is that I see zero effort.  I see a request for teh C0d3z and a promise not to cheat after receiving something that makes it far too easy to cheat.

What I, and probably others here, want to see is effort and some attempt.

1. Do you know how to print text to the screen like you see in the requirements?  Do you know how to print text at all?  If so, make the print routines and state this.
2. Do you know how to generate random numbers?  If so, say so in your question and we see effort.
3. Do you know how to receive input from the user?
4. Do you know what an array is?
5. Do you know how to save code in your editor and compile it?

You can see that without any sort of background or starting code, we don't know where you are in your learning.

So...

Post an attempt at solving your problem in your question.  If you are truly so new to coding that you cannot do this, then you need to sit down with your professor / TA / whomever and tell them this.  Reading through your teaching material (textbook or whatever) should help a whole lot as well.  This assignment feels like something I would see towards the end of a beginner's C class.  If this is where you are, and you really have no clue what to do, then you may need to retake the class.